# GCP: test a compute image locally

Tags: vagrant, google-compute-engine, packer, google-compile-testing

In order to be able to do some tests before create a Virtual Machine on GCP, I'd like to be able to export a disk image (this is the easy part, no pb) et use locally.

My idea would be to start a vagrant box from it but I didn't find how to achieve it. I am open to any other tools, as long as I can avoid to do everything on a billing & distant VM.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, have you look into this article [1] ?
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image